# interpretation of correlations

Tags: correlation

I have 3 variables. My DV $Z$ of interest are reaction times, IV $A$ and IV $B$ are performance scores in psychometric tests. Looking at bivariate correlations, $A$ and $B$ are negatively correlated (-.40), $A$ and $Z$ are marginally negatively correlated (-.10) and $B$ and $Z$ are highly negatively correlated (-.50). Putting $A$ and $B$ in a regression model with criterion $Z$ leads to two negative standardized coefficients about -.40. 
In other words, If I am good in $A$, I have a fast reaction. If I am good in $B$, I have a fast reaction. But if I am good in $A$, I am not good in $B$?! Is this logical?

Coding of the variables should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer lies in the fact that some of the correlations are simply not significant in the sense that a large correlation factor might arise from a chance alignment of a small number of points. Looking at the different correlation coefficients, I would advance that maybe the correlation between Z and A is not that significant in this sense. A way of testing for this this is to do a [permutation test](http://www.statistics.com/glossary&term_id=659) (as a simple non-parametric test) which would associate a p-value to the correlation coefficient.

So in a nutshell, given the information you provided, the results you obtained are not fully incompatible.

Comment: the bivariate correlation is not significant, nor the predictor. still, a standardized beta of -.36 is hard to ignore. i will do what you told me

Comment: @pedrofigueira: Could you explain in what way 'significance' is relevant here? To the OP: could you please provide some graphical description of the situation? This is much easier than to speculate using correlations.

Comment: @Michael Mayer I just did. Hope it helps.